# Cordova - save MySQL last downloaded data offline

Tags: php, android, mysql, html, cordova

Im new to cordova mobile app development. So I built a page using html5. Based on my research, I found out that cordova cannot proccess .php page. So I implemented ajax to send and receive request from my hosting. I'ts working on the web and on the mobile itself. Now the thing is, I want to make the app accessible offline. So my rough idea is to download all the data from MySQL at first start, and schedule update every week because the data is rarely updated.

My concern is, am I thinking of the right technique? or is there any better way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should think about all your queries, they would fail if you try to access your remote database. You should try to set up a local database to query the data you got from your download from mySQL. I am not sure about SQL, but I have used mini-mongo for noSQL data. Then you can intercept your queries and if you are offline, you query the local database instead.
Good Luck.